# Action Script 3 NumericStepper validation for empty value

Tags: actionscript-3, validation, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I have a simple NumericStepper which looks like this:

```
<mx:NumericStepper id="nsPort"
minimum="0"
maximum="65535"
stepSize="1"
value="{PORT_DEFAULT}"/>
```

I wrote a Validator for it (which doesn't work as I expect):

```
<mx:NumberValidator
required="true"
source="{nsPort}"
property="value"/>
```

However, every time I don't enter anything into NumericStepper it passes zero, not NULL or something else, which is...well...a valid value. I suspect that this is done on purpose. So, how can I make blank value at NumbericStepper to be invalid?
Please note that I'm restricted to a ver.3 of Action Script.

Answer (score 1):

Example code base from https://flexscript.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/flex-creating-custom-validators/ with a little modification:

```
package flexScript
{
     import mx.validators.ValidationResult;
     import mx.validators.Validator;

 //Class should extend mx.validators.Validator
 public class NumericStepperValidator extends Validator {

        public function NumericStepperValidator() {
            // Call base class constructor.
            super();
        }

        // Class should override the doValidation() method.
        //doValidation method should accept an Object type parameter
        override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array {
            // create an array to return.
            var ValidatorResults:Array = new Array();
            // Call base class doValidation().
            ValidatorResults = super.doValidation(value);       
            // Return if there are errors.
            if (ValidatorResults.length > 0)
                return ValidatorResults;

            if (String(value).length == 0)
             return ValidatorResults;
            if ( value == 0)//as your required.
             return ValidatorResults;

               var RegPattern:RegExp = /\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/; //Change to your customize regExpression
            var a:Array = RegPattern.exec(String(value));
               if (a == null)
               {
                ValidatorResults.push(new ValidationResult(true, null, "NumbericStepper Error","You must enter an Number"));
                return ValidatorResults;
               }
             return ValidatorResults;
        }
    }
}

<flexScript:NumbericStepperValidator source="{{nsPort}}" property="number"/>
```

Comment: Custom validator is a nice thing but catching value == 0 is not what I need... Zero value itself is OK. What I really want to know is was this zero entered by user or returned by NumericStepper as unboxed null. Or just get the real boxed value...

Comment: “unboxes null” scenario is break through the FLEX component life cycle, for example while the box component is rendering try to access its value, you should validate the component self instance is null at first, then to get its value;